# android: simple LinearLayout and fill_parent question

Tags: xml, android, layout, user-interface

I'm sure I am missing something simple...

**Background:**

I am new to android and UI design, and I just wanted to play around with layouts. Right now I want to stack a checkbox on top of text label. I am using the following xml layout which *works fine*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check_box_text" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dummy_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummy_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Tests (just to get a feel for how things works):**

- Scenario 1) When I set the `CheckBox`'s `layout_height` to `"fill_parent"`, the `CheckBox` takes up the whole screen and is aligned center (i.e. - the `TextView` disappears).
- Scenario 2) If I  *instead* set the `TextView`'s `layout_height` to `"fill_parent"`, the `CheckBox` does **NOT** disappear. In fact, nothing disappears, and the layout looks the same as the above xml where everything is pushed to the top-left.

**The Question (and comments):**

How come Scenario 1 works the way it works?

This behavior seems inconsistent to me. I thought that `fill_parent` is only supposed to let the element fill up whatever space is available in the parent. So to me, it seems that the `TextView` should get whatever space it *needs* (since it is `wrap_content`), but the `CheckBox` should take up the rest of the space (so the `TextView` would be forced to the bottom of the screen, but not invisible). In other words... Scenario 2 makes sense to me, but scenario 1 does not.

Please explain :-).

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: You might want to read this(if not already): How android draws Views? Link :   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LinearLayout` measures it children as a single step one by one, so in your first example 
it sees that first child want to have all available height it gives it to it.
In your second example it gives all available place to the second child.
If you want checkbox to take all the place except place needed for text box you should change 
layout_height of checkbox to `wrap_parent` and set `layout_weight` property of each child, layout weight indicates how much of available place **after** all children were measured should be add to the each of them. To be more specific the way it works by steps:
1) Parent of LinearLayout tells linear layout how big it can be
2) LinearLayout asks all it children in order they specified about their layout params and distributes available space.
3) If any free space is still available it distributes it between children according to their weight's ( layout weight is between 0 and 1 , 0 - by default)
Hope it helps
**Edit:**
I've checked `LinearLayout` source code and found out what if a linear layout had a `FILL_PARENT` layout params and not zero weight measuring code will set layout height to `WRAP_CONTENT` and later distribute space between all children according to weights.

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem completely correct, but you seem close. When I set the weight of the checkbox to 1... but KEEP it as fill_parent for the height... it works as expected. Meaning... the renderer doesn't just give the checkbox all of the space once it sees fill_parent for the height. So everything you say about the weights makes sense to me... but I don't see when/where "fill_parent" fits into this layout algorithm. Do you?

Comment: see my edit for further info. That is why I like SO it always a chance to learn something :)

Comment: If I could give you more than one up vote, I would.  It was driving me NUTS trying to figure out how to have views fill all the available space, with more space going to one than another.  I was using a hodgepodge of relative layouts and not getting very far.